# Analysing an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Analyse the integrals to tell which can be expressed in elementary functions. The two integrals are $$\frac {x}{\sqrt {x^4+10x^2-96x-71}},\frac {x}{\sqrt {x^4+10x^2-96x-72}} $$. I just typed (hardest integrals to solve) and these intgrals were in one of the answers on quora. So I am just wondering if there is some kind of algorithm or analysis we can use to show which can expressed in elemantary functions and which not. I dont want exact antiderivatives just yes or no with a proof! Thanks!

Comment: Bleh, anti-derivatives?  I prefer bounds to work with ;P

Comment: [This may help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral).

Comment: @ Simply beautiful art that is a good answer but the square root in denominator is kind of irritating can you tell me what can we do there?

Comment: the first integral leads to an elliptic function, the second one also